# $A\otimes_k l$ is faithful flat extension of $A$

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, homological-algebra

Let $A$ be $k$- algebra and $l$ be finite extension of field $k$. Prove $B = A\otimes_k l$ is a faithful flat extension of $A$.

---

My attempt: let $M$ be arbitary $A$- module, therefore $M\otimes_AB = M\otimes_A A\otimes_k l = M \otimes_k l$ since $l$ is $k$-vector space it's free therefore it's also flat, and tensoring with $B$ over $A$ has same effect as tensoring of $l$ over $k$, therefore it's flat.

**And left to prove it's faithful**, i.e.

$$0\to M\otimes_A B \to N\otimes_AB \to Q\otimes_AB\to 0$$
is exact implies $$0\to M\to N \to Q\to 0$$
is exact, I don't know how to prove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that exactness of a sequence can be regarded as a statement purely about the underlying abelian groups of the sequence. As field extensions are faithfully flat, this shows you that $B$ is faithfully flat with what you have already done.

Indeed, if the sequence $0\to M\otimes_A B \to N\otimes_AB \to Q\otimes_AB\to 0$ is exact, then the sequence $0\to M\otimes_k l \to N\otimes_k l \to Q\otimes_k l\to 0$ is aswell. If we regard this as a sequence of $k$-modules we obtain that $0\to M\to N\to Q\to 0$ is a exact sequence of $k$-modules by flatness of $l$. But as explained, exactness doesn't depend on the underlying ring, so it is an exact sequence of $A$-modules.

Comment: Thank you @imtrying46 , can you provide a bit hint why field extensions are faithfully flat? I know it's flat since the field extension is free and direct sum commute with tensor product, however I don't know how to prove it's faithful, it does not appear in the textbook.

Comment: Ah I see, needs to use that direct sum of faithful module is faithful, therefore for $l \cong k^n$ it's sufficient to assume $n =1$